# Determining which formula descibes an English sentence in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let the natural language sentence be: "For every person, there is a food that the person likes".

Define P(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a person". F(x) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ is a food". L(x, y) = "$\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{x}$ likes $\underbrace{\_\_\_}_{y}$".

Which one of these formulas represent the English sentence in FOL?

1.) $\forall x. \exists y. P(x) \implies (F(y) \land L(x, y))$

2.) $\forall x. \exists y. (P(x) \land F(y)) \implies L(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one.

Following natural language, we have to write: $\forall x \ (Px \to \exists y \ (Fy \land L(x,y))$.

Using [Prenex transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication), due to the fact that $y$ is not free in $Px$, we get the equivalent:

> $\forall x \ \exists y \ (Px \to (Fy \land L(x,y))$.

Comment: What does the second formula try to represent?

Comment: @Qwaster - see [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)); the second one is $∀x ∃y (Px→ (Fy \to L(x,y))$.